# NSURLSession: It is possible with no authentication NSURLSession ( Swift )

Tags: swift, session, request, authorization, nsurlsession

I would like with an API -Key and authenticate user . I have the message " Session URL Task Succeeded : HTTP 200 " get in the Console . Unfortunately, I always get the message of the page " {" message " : " . Authorization has been denied for this request " } " . I spent hours looking for and found a solution . I ask for your help . Here is my code :

```
    let sessionConfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()


    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)


    let URL = NSURL(string: "https://api.testhomepage.com/api/contact")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL!)

    // Headers

    request.addValue("ARRAffinity=259dfjiehfs315d7249df8805c7895a98c4cbd3327ffdcb82aaa16317f2e6", forHTTPHeaderField: "Cookie")
    request.addValue("Basic dWVzQGp1bGl0ZafdgfvcfgeDcyZS1hZWEyLTQzYmVmMjFhNDMxZQ==", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("api.testhomepage.com", forHTTPHeaderField: "Host")
    request.addValue("//api.testhomepage.com/api/contact: POST", forHTTPHeaderField: "https")
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    // JSON Body


    /* Start a new Task */
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            // Success
            let statusCode = (response as! NSHTTPURLResponse).statusCode
            print("URL Session Task Succeeded: HTTP \(statusCode)")
            let myURLString = "https://api.testhomepage.com/api/contact"

            if let myURL = NSURL(string: myURLString) {
                var error: NSError?
                let myhtml = try! NSString(contentsOfURL: myURL, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

                if let error = error {
                    print("Error : \(error)")
                } else {
                    print("HTML : \(myhtml)")
                }
            } else {
                print("Error: \(myURLString) doesn't seem to be a valid URL")
            }

        }
        else {
            // Failure
            print("URL Session Task Failed: %@", error!.localizedDescription);
        }
    }

    task.resume()

        }
```

This is in the console:

URL Session Task Succeeded: HTTP 200
HTML : {"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}

Comment: I see a spacing between Basic and dwv... is there suppose to be an underscore or something?

Comment: There is nothing in between , without Basic I get 500 Error . With space I get 200 Connection Succeeded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `request.setvalue("", forHTTPHeaderField: "")` instead of `request.addValue("", forHTTPHeaderField: "")`

Comment: request.addValue I replaced with request.setValue . Nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

You *cannot* populate the Authentication header yourself, period.  That header is owned by the URL loading system, and is populated based on credentials in the user's keychain.

You can learn about how to do authentication by reading the authentication chapter of [URL Session Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/AuthenticationChallenges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009507-SW1).  Note that the examples are for NSURLConnection, but the rest of the text applies to both.

Alternatively, you can store the credentials in the keychain as an Internet Password item, as described in [Keychain Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/03tasks/tasks.html).